# Proper ways to upgrade a module in the Magento Cloud

Tags: composer, magento-cloud

I was wondering what the proper steps are to upgrade a third-party vendor module. This is what I have done:

- Removed the old version and added the new version in the composer.json file.
- Pushed to GitHub.

However, Composer is still downloading the old version of the module during deployment. I expected it to download the new version that I added to the composer.json file.

What am I missing? Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you did not need to remove the extension from the `composer.json file`. The proper way to upgrade the extension is by using the composer itself. You can use the below syntax to upgrade the extension using Composer.

```
composer require vendor_name/extension_name:extension_version
```

Kindly use the above command on your local env from the root directory of Magento.

Please accept the answer if your issue is fixed.